# envelopeid stamp c# sdk

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm trying to remove the envelope id stamp from my pdfs via sdk, but without luck. Can someone guide me into how to remove it?

I've tried to remove it from

> Settings -> Send Settings

But It already not selected. By the way, it's disabled to me.
[Settings -> Send Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pnm0m.png)

And I've tried to make the EnvelopeIdStamping = "false"; when creating my envelope.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to the Sending settings and enabling it, but then disabling the 'Include Envelope ID by default' option. I believe that even if you have 'Enable including the Envelope ID on the document' disabled, it will still default to adding it, so you want 'Enable including the Envelope ID on the document' enabled and 'Include Envelope ID by default' disabled.

If you're still running into trouble, please open a support case with us here: https://support.docusign.com/s/?language=en_US

Comment: the problem is that this option to me is DISABLED and I can't enable It to test what you've suggested.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pnm0m.png